# How to aggregate a function from the master class - Python

Tags: python, oop, aggregation

How can I get the following code to work, without getting the error of `TypeError: myMasterFunction() missing 1 required positional argument: 'master'`

Example program:

```
from tkinter import *
class printing():
    def printSentence(self):
        #Call print_name function
        myMasterClass().print_name()
        print("Tom")

class myMasterClass():
    def __init__(self,master):
        super(myMasterClass,self).__init__(master)
    def print_name(self):
        print("My name is...")

printing().printSentence()
root = Tk()
myGUI = myMasterClass(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Many thanks. P.S I'm new to OOP so I don't know for sure if this is aggregation, but I don't want to do inheritance.

Comment: The code you posted can't possibly give the error `myMasterFunction() missing 1 required positional argument` because `myMasterFunction` hasn't been defined.

Comment: @BryanOakley oh sorry. `myMasterClass` instead

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you are trying to achieve, but when you are creating `print` **class**, you are overriding the original `print` **function** in the namespace. And because your print **class** doesn't take any parameters (no `__init__` provided), calling `print("Tom")` will throw an error. That's the first one. Other one is in calling `super(myMasterClass,self).__init__(master)`. As you can see, you are not using any inheritance in this class, which by default will inherit from `object` class anyway. And object class doesn't take any parameters too, so trying to provide `master` argument will result in error. Overall I've no idea what you want to achieve in here, but I think it would be much easier to use decorators instead of something like that, if you want to add some extra things to the default `print` function.

Comment: print("Tom") actually only prints the string 'Tom'. The problem has nothing to do with the names given to the classes and function.

Comment: This isn't my actual program btw. I have just made one up to demonstrate my problem

Comment: I have changed the code slightly to show that I have a GUI involved. Is it possible you could tell me how I fix this please?

Comment: As I said. The problem is in `myMasterClass().print_name()`. Your `myMasterClass` require an argument to be passed in your `__init__` definition. You are not passing it in your `printing.printSentence()` function.